# How to save Items to database after payment successed via stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to save the items that the user bought in the database only if the payment process has been successfully completed. According to the documentation, I need to listen to the 'payment_intent.succeeded' event from the webhook route to determine if the payment was successful or not.

my code:

payment route:

```
app.post("/payment", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { products } = req.body;
    const params = {
      submit_type: "pay",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      billing_address_collection: "auto",
      shipping_options: [
        { shipping_rate: "shr_1N2Wx9AajIUGDg9S9HJNtyY5" },
        { shipping_rate: "shr_1N1xxSAajIUGDg9SjrbMqcbx" },
      ],
      line_items: products.map((item) => {
        return {
          price_data: {
            currency: "usd",
            product_data: {
              name: item.name,
              images: [item.image],
            },
            unit_amount: item.price * 100,
          },
          adjustable_quantity: {
            enabled: true,
            minimum: 1,
          },
          quantity: item.quantity,
        };
      }),
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: "http://localhost:5173/cart",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:5173/cart",
    };

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(session));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
});
```

webhook route:

```
app.post(
  "/webhook",
  express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
  (request, response) => {
    const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
    let event;
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }

    switch (event.type) {
      case "payment_intent.succeeded":
        const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }
    response.send();
  }
);
```

In the webhook route, after the 'case "payment_intent.succeeded":' statement, how can I retrieve the line_items in order to add them to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the line_items, instead of listening to the 'payment_intent.succeeded' event, you should listen to the 'checkout.session.completed' event. By doing so, you'll be able to fetch the line items related to the checkout session. Here's an example of how to properly expand the line items and save them to the database.

First, update your webhook handler to listen to 'checkout.session.completed':

```
switch (event.type) {  
  case 'checkout.session.completed':  
    const session = event.data.object;  
      
    // Handle the checkout session completion and save line items to the database here  
    handleCheckoutSession(session);  
    break;  
  // ... other cases  
}
```

Then, implement the handleCheckoutSession function to fetch and save the line_items:

```
async function handleCheckoutSession(session) {  
  // You need to have stripe imported and initialized with your API key  
  const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session.id, {  
    expand: ['line_items'],  
  });  
  
  const lineItems = checkoutSession.line_items.data;  
  
  // Save the lineItems to your database  
  // Your logic for saving the items to the database goes here  
}
```

By using this approach, you will be able to retrieve and save the line_items once the checkout session has been completed successfully. For additional reference, you can check the Stripe documentation for fulfilling orders at: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders